# Assortativity given an attribute file in NetworkX Python

Tags: python, networkx

I'm working with NetworkX package from python and I want to obtain the assortativity coefficient of my network given the node attributes in a text file.

I have two tab-delimited files:
(1) attribute file: in the first column there is the name of the nodes; in the second column the origin of these nodes. Something like this:

```
11264   E
9410    E
2746    R
7432    R
8424    E
```

(2) edge file: the network itself, where the two first columns are the nodes for which there is an edge, 3rd column is the percentage of identity from the blast; 4th column is the mutual cover between these two sequences.

```
4275    5402    97.04   97.83
6268    6338    98.49   100.0
2175    2178    99.26   100.0
4461    4777    97.06   98.55
11882   4129    98.4    100.0
```

So, in my code, I create a dictionary for the attribute file, so every node has a value, which is either "E" or "R". When I compute the assortativity based on this dictionary, this error pops up:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  r=(t-s)/(1-s)
nan
```

I've checked around and I know it must be something related to divide by 0 or NA, but I cannot figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx

origin = {}
infile=open("attrib_file.tsv","r")
for line in infile:
    t = line[:-1].split("\t")
    origin[t[0]] = t[1]
infile.close()

G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.read_edgelist("edge_file.tsv", delimiter="\t", data=(('ID',float),('Coverage', float)), encoding='utf-8')
print(nx.attribute_assortativity_coefficient(G, 'origin'))
```

I'm working with python 3.5.1 and networkx 1.11

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the origin column contains strings. If you change to an integer, do you still have the same error?

Comment: Yes, the same error appears, changing just the 2nd column or both of them

Comment: Can you try the example from the doc ? >>> G=nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_nodes_from([0,1],color='red')
>>> G.add_nodes_from([2,3],color='blue')
>>> G.add_edges_from([(0,1),(2,3)])
>>> print(nx.attribute_assortativity_coefficient(G,'color'))

Comment: Yes, I already tried it and it works fine. 
It seems to be related to the fact that the nodes attributes are coming from a dictionary and not by adding them with .add_nodes_from()

And in the example from the doc, the attribute is string, not integer. I don't know, it doesn't make sense...

Comment: You're right it's a string. By any chance, does a networkx update could help?

Comment: Nope... I have now the version 2.1 and it pops up the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, it might be an issue with `dict` attributes.

*Here, I am using python 3.6 and networkx 2.1.*

### Setup

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

attr_file = pd.read_clipboard()
attr_file
```

[out]:

```
    name    origin
0   11264   E
1   9410    E
2   2746    R
3   7432    R
4   8424    E
```

I changed the sample you gave :

```
edge_list = pd.read_clipboard()
edge_list
```

[out]:

```
n1  n2  percent coverage
0   11264   9410    97.04   97.83
1   9410    2746    98.49   100.00
2   11264   2178    99.26   100.00
3   9410    8424    97.06   98.55
4   7432    2746    98.40   100.00
```

### Create nodes

```
G = nx.Graph()
for i,node in attr_file.iterrows():
    G.add_node(node['name'], origin=node['origin'])

G.nodes(data=True)
```

[out]:

```
NodeDataView({11264: {'origin': 'E'}, 9410: {'origin': 'E'}, 2746: {'origin': 'R'}, 7432: {'origin': 'R'}, 8424: {'origin': 'E'}})
```

### Create edges

```
for i, edge in edge_list.iterrows():
    G.add_edge(edge.n1, edge.n2, percent=edge.percent, coverage=edge.coverage)
```

### Compute assortativity

```
nx.attribute_assortativity_coefficient(G, 'origin')
```

[out]:

```
0.2592592592592593
```

Comment: Fantastic, it worked!! Thank you very very much! Gracias :)

Comment: You're welcome. Your intuition was good. Please, don't forget to accept the answer.